# Create a variable # of Flask-WTF forms or submit multiple forms with one submit button

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, flask-wtforms

I am completely self taught so I apologize if my code is a mess. I am trying to create a full stack planning tool.

Jobs will come in and be displayed on the webpage as shown in the snapshot below.[Website snippit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNdPi.png)

I would like the user be able to enter the dates equipment is available and hit submit so I could grab that info and send it in an email automatically to a planner.

I am getting stuck on the following: It does not seem that I could have one submit button submit multiple forms simultaneously which means I'll have to make multiple forms. If I have to make multiple forms, they will have to generate as I iterate over a job list because the job list will be of variable size. On top of that, I need to store the info as each submit button is hit.

Here is my python code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, DateField, TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from WO_Gatherer import WoHandler
import random

work_orders = WoHandler()

liquids_jobs, ss_jobs, line_116_jobs,lyo_jobs = work_orders.room_and_department()


login_key = '1234'


class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField(label='Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField(label='Login Key', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField(label='Log In')

class PmcForm(FlaskForm):
    date = DateField(label='Date')
    comment = TextAreaField(label='Comment')
    submit = SubmitField(label='Submit')


app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)
app.secret_key = "some-secret-string"


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    login_form = MyForm()
    return render_template('index.html', form=login_form)


@app.route('/<department>', methods=['POST'])
def pmc(department):
    global login_key
    global liquids_jobs, ss_jobs, line_116_jobs, lyo_jobs
    form = PmcForm()
    if department == 'liquids':
        job_packet = liquids_jobs
    elif department == 'SS':
        job_packet = ss_jobs
    elif department == 'L116':
        job_packet = line_116_jobs
    elif department == 'Lyo':
        job_packet = lyo_jobs
    data = {
        'email': request.form['email'],
        'key': request.form['password']
    }
    if data['key'] == login_key:
        return render_template(f'{department}.html', jobs=job_packet, form=form)
    else:
        return '<h1>Incorrect Login Key</h1>'


@app.route('/success', methods=['POST'])
def success():
    data = {
        'Dates': request.form['date'],
        'Comments': request.form['comment']
    }
    return f'<h1>Response successfully submitted! Thank you.{data}</h1>'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and an example of my pmc page

```
    {% include 'header.html' %}

<section class='header {% block color %}{% endblock %}'>
  <img class="card-img-top header-icon" src="static/images/{% block image %}{% endblock %}.svg" alt="Card image cap">
    <h1 class="header-text">{% block title %}{% endblock %} Production Maintenance Coordination</h1>
</section>

<section class='pmc-table'>
  <table class="table">
          <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">WO Number</th>
                <th scope="col">Description</th>
                <th scope="col">Rooms</th>
                <th scope="col">Impact</th>
                <th scope="col">Est Comp Time</th>
                <th scope="col">Input Form</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {% block content %}{% endblock %}
          </tbody>
  </table>

    <div class="submit-button">
        <form action="{{ url_for('success') }}" method="POST">{% block button %}{% endblock %}</form>
    </div>

</section>




{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

And the page that renders in the snippit example

```
    {% extends 'pmc.html' %}

{% block color %}blue{% endblock %}
{% block image %}liquids{% endblock %}
{% block title %}Liquids{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% for job in jobs %}
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">{{ job[0] }}</th>
              <td>{{ job[1] }}</td>
              <td>{% for room in job[5] %}{{ room + '\n'}}{% endfor %}</td>
              <td>{{ job[2] }}</td>
              <td>{{ job[3] }}</td>
              <td>Date: <br> {{ form.date }} <br> Comments: <br> {{ form.comment }}</td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block button %}{{ form.submit }}{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that.  You are looking for [Field Enclosures](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#field-enclosures) in WTForms.
Add `FieldList` and `FormField` to your wtforms imports and then:

```
class PmcFields(FlaskForm):
    date = DateField(label='Date')
    comment = TextAreaField(label='Comment')
class PmcForm(FlaskForm):
    pmc_fields = FieldList(FormField(PmcFields))
    submit = SubmitField(label='Submit')
```

Then in your `pmc(department)` route, after setting a value for job packet:

```
form = PmcForm()
for job in job_packet:
    form.pmc_fields.append_entry(PmcFields())
```